# 2 node RAC: gv$encryption_wallet has wallet in different locations?

Tags: oracle-12c

Linux x86_64 Exadata X8, Oracle 12.1.0.2, 2-node RAC.

1. I created a wallet on node 1. In $TNS_ADMIN, sqlnet.ora contains "wallet_location=/u01/oracle/correct_dir"
2. Node 2, I spaced creating sqlnet there or defining $TNS_ADMIN. I caught this, created the environment var, copied sqlnet.ora there so now "wallet_location" on node 2="/u01/oracle/correct_dir". However gv$encryption_wallet shows this

   **INST_ID     CON_ID WRL_TYPE  WRL_PARAMETER                 STATUS**

   ```
     1          0 FILE      /u01/oracle/correct_dir/      OPEN
     2          0 FILE      $ORACLE_HOME/<somedir>/wallet NOT_AVAILABLE
   ```
3. "ls -la $ORACLE_HOME/wallet" returns "No such file or directory"
4. On node 2 I issued "ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN IDENTIFIED BY "" CONTAINER=ALL; It said, "keystore altered"
5. Now, gv$encryption_wallet shows this:

   **INST_ID     CON_ID WRL_TYPE  WRL_PARAMETER                 STATUS**

   ```
     1          0 FILE      /u01/oracle/correct_dir/      OPEN
     2          0 FILE      $ORACLE_HOME/<somedir>/wallet OPEN
   ```

So where is node 2 getting the above dir? How is it opening a wallet but showing an non-existent directory? How do I update the instance so it shows the correct one?

Thank you,
OraBrick

Answer (score 0):

all -- in this case the answer is simple: If you add a missing sqlnet.ora to your $TNS_ADMIN dir and open the keystore, Oracle will look for sqlnet.ora, find it, find the wallet and open it. Oracle apparently updates v$encryption_wallet.status column but "not" v$encryption_wallet.**wrl_parameter**. For that you must restart the instance on that node. I dunno. After that it will read sqlnet.ora and all will be right in the world again (at least my tiny part of it)

**INST_ID CON_ID WRL_TYPE WRL_PARAMETER STATUS**

1          0 FILE      /u01/oracle/correct_dir/      OPEN

2          0 FILE      /u01/oracle/correct_dir/      OPEN

Thanks for those that took the time to read my post.